# What kind of research can be done with genomic data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bioinformatics, data

It is well known that science has given us large amounts of free accessible data, such as https://www.1000genomes.org and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank. How can we play around with the data and apply data science/machine learning to it? What could be some ideas?

My own ideas:

- Biological data visualisation
- Gene prediction using hidden-markov-model

Any more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Determine the function of genes and the elements that regulate genes
  throughout the genome.
- Find variations in the DNA sequence among people and determine their
  significance. The most common type of genetic variation is known as a
  single nucleotide polymorphism or SNP (pronounced “snip”).  These
  small differences may help predict a person’s risk of particular
  diseases and response to certain medications.
- Discover the 3-dimensional structures of proteins and identify their
  functions.
- Explore how DNA and proteins interact with one another and with the
  environment to create complex living systems.
- Develop and apply genome-based strategies for the early detection,
  diagnosis, and treatment of disease.
- Sequence the genomes of other organisms, such as the rat, cow, and
  chimpanzee, in order to compare similar genes between species.
- Develop new technologies to study genes and DNA on a large scale and
  store genomic data efficiently.
- Continue to explore the ethical, legal, and social issues raised by
  genomic research.

[Source: https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/handbook/genomicresearch?show=all](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/handbook/genomicresearch?show=all)

Answer (score 1):

You may build models to classify genomes by population.
Run unsupervised learning (clustering) to see if populations are reconstructed in the model.
Build models to infer missing genotypes

To do a Scalable DNA analysis you may check [Adam](http://bdgenomics.org/) software based on Apache Spark